# How to link with libdl library in cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, linker, libdl

My application depends on OpenSSL.  So, I downloaded and built OpenSSL, and placed the static libraries (`libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a`) I require in known directory I have control over.  In my application's cmake file, I use the `find_library` command to determine the full path of each library, store the paths in a list variable, and add that list variable to the `target_link_libraries` command.  That works, insofar as the OpenSSL symbols are visible to my application.

OpenSSL further depends on the "Dynamic linking loader" library (a.k.a. `libdl`).  I know that the OpenSSL build used the `-ldl` compiler option because I can see it in the build output.

On my Linux develpment machine, the `libdl` library seems to have already been installed.  The evidence is:

1. `libdl.so` and `libdl.so.2` (which are symbolic links to the actual `libdl-2-17.so` library file) exist in what seems to be a standard directory for such things:  `/usr/lib64`
2. When I run `man dlclose`, I get the expected manual page about the "Dynamic linking loader" library.

However, when I build my application, I get linker errors like the following.   The `libdl` library is definitely **not** being found.

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../install/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib64/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

### Question 1

Should cmake have been able to find `libdl.so` on its own?

### Question 2

In my application's cmake file, I can use the `find_library` command to determine the full path of the `libdl` library, and add that path to the `target_link_libraries` command.  Notice that I did not have to give it a path hint.  That works, but it feels like a workaround.

Should it be necessary for me to explicitly search for the full path of `libdl.so`?

### Question 3

Is there a more proper way in cmake to link with a "standard" library such as `libdl`?

### cmake file

The following are the relevant snippets of my application's cmake file.

```
...

#------------------------------
# Search for openssl libraries.
set( OPENSSL_LIBRARIES )
find_library( temp libssl.a PATHS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rd_party/" )
list( APPEND OPENSSL_LIBRARIES ${temp} )
unset( temp CACHE )

find_library( temp libcrypto.a PATHS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/3rd_party/" )
list( APPEND OPENSSL_LIBRARIES ${temp} )
unset( temp CACHE )

#------------------------------
# Search for dl library.
# TODO:  Is this workaround really necessary?
find_library( DL_LIBRARY libdl.so  )

...

#------------------------------
# My application.
add_executable( myapp main.cxx )

set_target_properties( myapp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-g" )

target_link_libraries( myapp
  ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}

  # TODO:  Is this workaround really necessary?
  ${DL_LIBRARY}
)

install( TARGETS myapp DESTINATION ${BIN_INSTALL_DIR} )
```

### cmake version

I am using cmake version 2.8.12, but the particular version may not be important.

Comment: If this library is installed in the standard location (which it looks like it is), you should not need `find_library()`. Did you try just using `target_link_libraries(myapp ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} dl)`?

Comment: In short: When you link openssl **statically**, you need to **manually** link all libraries it depends, including `dl` library.

Comment: Thank you @squareskittles and @Tsyvarev for the useful comments and links to duplicate questions.  One of the other linked questions mentions adding the `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}` variable to the `target_link_libraries` clause.  The value of that variable is `dl`.  That works, and it is more appropriate that using `find_library` to determine the path of that library myself.